# Recommended way of passing cacheKey to selectFromResult and onQueryStarted in RTKQ

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

In [RTKQ-documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries#selecting-data-from-a-query-result) example `cacheKey` is `undefined`, but usually that is not the case. My current solution is to save `cacheKey` in a slice which makes it available both to `selectFromResult` and `onQueryStarted` (essentially everywhere) but I feel it is less than perfect. Is there some recommended way of storing and reusing cacheKey in RTKQ?

Comment: In `selectFromResult` you essentially pass it into the query on the same statement, so it should be directly available for you? As for `onQueryStarted`, what do you want to use it for? Generally you should only need the arguments, if at all, but never the cache key itself (which is a string)?

Comment: @phry if I pass only `id` to list items as it is recommended than list item has to know  also the `cacheKey` which I can pass from parent so that I could use `selectFromResult`. In `onQueryStarted` I need it for optimistic/pessimistic updates so that I could know which cache to update.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using wrong terms here. `cacheKey` is an internal string representation of your argument and you will **never** interact with that string in RTK-Query.

You will need the *same argument* in some cases.

In `onQueryStarted` of a query, you might just be able `updateCachedData` from [the lifecylce api](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#onquerystarted), so you do not need the argument.

For `selectFromResult`, you will need to pass the same argument into the hook as you did elsewhere. In that case, you can either pass it down to a child using props or share it using Redux state.

Comment: But isn't `updateCachedData` available for query endpoints only and optimistic/pessimistic updates are performed in mutation?

Comment: Sorry, I read over that part of your answer above. In that case, yes, sharing that query argument in some global way like an external slice is the way to go.